# No module named unusual_prefix_*

Tags: python, pickle, airflow

I tried to run the [Python Operator Example](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_python_operator.py) in my Airflow installation. The installation has deployed webserver, scheduler and worker on the same machine and runs with no complaints for all non-PytohnOperator tasks. The task fails, complaining that the module "unusual_prefix_*" could not be imported, where * is the name of the file containing the DAG.

The full stacktrace:

```
['/usr/bin/airflow', 'run', 'tutorialpy', 'print_the_context', '2016-08-23T10:00:00', '--pickle', '90', '--local']
[2016-08-29 11:35:20,054] {__init__.py:36} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2016-08-29 11:35:20,175] {configuration.py:508} WARNING - section/key [core/fernet_key] not found in config
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/airflow", line 90, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/opt/mf-airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 214, in run
    DagPickle).filter(DagPickle.id == args.pickle).first()
  File "/opt/mf-airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2659, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "/opt/mf-airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2457, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "/opt/mf-airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 86, in instances
    util.raise_from_cause(err)
  File "/opt/mf-airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 202, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/opt/mf-airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 71, in instances
    rows = [proc(row) for row in fetch]
  File "/opt/mf-airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 428, in _instance
    loaded_instance, populate_existing, populators)
  File "/opt/mf-airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 486, in _populate_full
    dict_[key] = getter(row)
  File "/opt/mf-airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1253, in process
    return loads(value)
  File "/opt/mf-airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 260, in loads
    return load(file)
  File "/opt/mf-airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 250, in load
    obj = pik.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/opt/mf-airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 406, in find_class
    return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1124, in find_class
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named unusual_prefix_tutorialpy
[2016-08-29 11:35:20,498: ERROR/Worker-1] Command 'airflow run tutorialpy print_the_context 2016-08-23T10:00:00 --pickle 90 --local ' returned non-zero exit status 1
[2016-08-29 11:35:20,502: ERROR/MainProcess] Task airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command[01152b52-044e-4361-888c-ef2d45983c60] raised unexpected: AirflowException('Celery command failed',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/mf-airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/mf-airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/mf-airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 45, in execute_command
    raise AirflowException('Celery command failed')
AirflowException: Celery command failed
```

Comment: The pickled file referenced by the configuration likely contain a reference to this item from a custom module/class that is not available on this system. Figure out where/what this file is and try to restart your stack without it and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: @metatoaster: I guess you meant the line regarding `WARNING - section/key`. This one isn't a problem, I added the necessary config and it did not change anything. However, doing so I found at least a temporary workaround. Will post this as an answer.

Comment: no, not that, but that specifically that airflow for whatever reason had picked a object that is implemented by a module/class that does not exist.  This is also why `donot_pickle=True` will work because the loading of the pickle file is the problem - it contains an object that your installation of Python cannot find the module for (see the whole stack trace, especially towards the end).

Answer (score 3):

Using `donot_pickle=True` option ([see Documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/airflow/cli.html)) I got rid of the error. Probably not the best solution, but good enough for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered  this problem when running puckel/docker-airlfow on kubernetnes.

trun `donot_pickle` True or False don't work for me.

After some experiments I get rid of this problem by remove `-p` parameter from the paramters airlfow schduler/worker used to start process

`airflow scheduler -n 5 -p` -> `airflow scheduler -n 5`

`airflow worker -p` -> `airflow worker`

Answer (score 0):

This may happen because you have a custom import like this:

```
import tutorialpy # or something similar
```

Which causes [this code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/88b274c95b212b541ba19918880ae425856212be/airflow/models/dagbag.py#L296C1-L315C73) to run and it adds `unusual_prefix_`:

```
def _load_modules_from_file(self, filepath, safe_mode):
    if not might_contain_dag(filepath, safe_mode):
        # Don't want to spam user with skip messages
        if not self.has_logged:
            self.has_logged = True
            self.log.info("File %s assumed to contain no DAGs. Skipping.", filepath)
        return []

self.log.debug("Importing %s", filepath)
org_mod_name, _ = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(filepath)[-1])
path_hash = hashlib.sha1(filepath.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
mod_name = f'unusual_prefix_{path_hash}_{org_mod_name}'

if mod_name in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules[mod_name]

def parse(mod_name, filepath):
    try:
        loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(mod_name, filepath)
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(mod_name, loader)
...
```