# GCP Composer/Airflow calling Dataflow/beam throwing error

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

I have a GCP Cloud Composer environment with airflow version `composer-1.10.0-airflow-1.10.6` and python 3, 3.6 to be precise. I am calling an apache-beam pipeline on Dataflow using a `python_operator.PythonOperator`, operator. Here is the code snippet

Calling the pipeline function

```
test_greeting = python_operator.PythonOperator(
    task_id='python_pipeline',
    python_callable=run_pipeline
)
```

The pipeline function is as follows

```
def run_pipeline():
    print("Test Pipeline")

    pipeline_args=[
        "--runner","DataflowRunner",
        "--project","*****",
        "--temp_location","gs://******/temp",
        "--region","us-east1",
        "--job_name","job1199",
        "--zone","us-east1-b"

    ]

    pipeline_options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipe=beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    small_sum = (
        pipe
        | beam.Create([18,5,7,7,9,23,13,5])
        | "Combine Globally" >> beam.CombineGlobally(AverageFn())
        | 'Write results' >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://******/ouptut_from_pipline/combine')
    )

    run_result=pipe.run()
    run_result.wait_until_finish()

    return "True"
```

When I run this the pipeline execution runs in dataflow but fails with the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 648, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 150, in execute
    test_shuffle_sink=self._test_shuffle_sink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 116, in create_operation
    is_streaming=False)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 1032, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.create_operation
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 845, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.create_pgbk_op
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 903, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.PGBKCVOperation.__init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 290, in loads
    return dill.loads(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 275, in loads
    return load(file, ignore, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load
    return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 462, in find_class
    return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unusual_prefix_162ac8b7030d5bd1ff5f128a26483932d3968a4d_python_bash'
```

The beam version is `Apache Beam Python 3.6 SDK 2.19.0`.
I suspect the version of Python 3.6 may be the issue as calling the pipeline directly (as a runner) from my local system works fine and my local system is running python 3.7.

I cant find a way to test this theory though.

It would be helpful to get tips of how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please, add to your pipeline_args: job_name and region region (more [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#configuring-pipelineoptions-for-execution-on-the-cloud-dataflow-service)). Moreover, in run_pipeline() definition, add 4 spaces before print("Test Pipeline"). Let me know about the results.

Comment: @muscat made the changes you suggested. However no respite from the same error. I have a strong suspicion it is the Python version on Airflow which is 3.6. When I run the dataflow pipeline initiated from my local system on GCP Dataflow it runs just fine

Comment: I am about to reproduce your scenario, can you tell me if you've defined AverageFn class in your code? Because I'm getting error when calling the "Combine Globally" >> beam.CombineGlobally(AverageFn())

Comment: can you try using DataflowTemplateOperator operator? if you still want to stick to pythonOperator then you can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/39222486/9484528